# How to expose User.id in JSON response from Loopback

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a simple use case that for the life of me I can't seem to figure out:

I have a model "Employee" that is based on the Loopback "User" model.  My assumption is that the "id" of "Employee" would be the same as "User".

For the purpose of passing an Employee/User.id to an Angular.js route, I need to expose the Employee model's 'id' property in the RESTful response of the my Loopback API.  Any idea on where or how to do this?

So far the Employee.id is profiled with the string "objectid"--which of course is not going to give me the correct user when I perform a Employee.find().

Comment: What type of data source are you using? MongoDB?

Comment: Yes, MongoDB is the datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, upon a more thorough review of the actual data in the Mongodb database it appears that '_id' in both User and Employee tables were always being populated with "objectid".  This made me look at my models more closely.  I compared them to the [loopback-angular-admin](https://github.com/beeman/loopback-angular-admin)'s models--specifically their custom "user" model.  What I noticed was that I had '"idInjection": true' on mine whereas the loopback-angular-admin project did not.  So, I removed this property and VOILA: BSON/valid ObjectIds!

My models were generated with 'slc loopback:model'.  This command line appears to add the '"idInjection":true' property to the models it generates.  I don't know why this particular property would be problematic for Mongodb but the source of my original issue has been resolved.

[image: With Weird '_id' Value of "objectid"]
[image: Without Weird '_id' Values--Now Valid BSON]

Answer (score 1):

`User.id` is provided by LoopBack out-of-box. You can test this by adding a dummy user (via a `boot script`) and then browsing to `localhost:3000/explorer` to inspect the output of any `GET` request on the `User` object.

Comment: You are right superkhau.  Thank you for answering that portion of my question.  However, the original question left out an important detail:  I'm actually attempting to access an id of "Employee" which is based on "User".  My thought was the "id" of Employee would be that of User since I did not explicitly give the Employee model an "id" property.  I just checked Mongodb, however, and this is not the case.  The value of Employee "_id" in Mongo is "objectid"...and I don't know why.

Comment: Because MongoDB uses ObjectId by default. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/
I'm guessing you were thinking its like SQL where you set autogenerate on a column?

Comment: This post might help on the second part of your question: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/loopbackjs/id$20mongodb/loopbackjs/jf_DHzOAbV0/ASRgPusu350J